# Character Count

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to count the number of Words, Lines and characters(excluding whitespace). The only part I can't get to work is ignoring the whitespace for the character count.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File file = getValidFile();
    int count = wordCount(file);
    int lines = lineCount(file);
    int characters = characterCount(file);
    System.out.println("Total Words = " + count);
    System.out.println("Total Lines = " + lines);
    System.out.println("Total Characters = " + characters);

}
public static int characterCount(File file) throws IOException {
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",\\s*");;
        int characters = 0; // initialise the counter variable
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            inputFile.next(); //read in a word
            characters++; //count the word
        }
        inputFile.close();
        return characters;
    }
}
public static int lineCount(File file)throws IOException {
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        int lines = 0; // initialise the counter variable
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            inputFile.nextLine(); //read in a line
            lines++; //count the line
        }
        inputFile.close();
        return lines;
    }
}
public static int wordCount(File file) throws IOException {
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        int count = 0; // initialise the counter variable
        while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            inputFile.next(); //read in a word
            count++; //count the word
        }
        inputFile.close();
        return count;
    }
}
public static File getValidFile() 
{

    String filename;     // The name of the file
    File file;

    // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get a valid file name.
    do
    {
        /*for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++ )
            {*/
        System.out.print("Enter the name of a file: ");
        filename = keyboard.nextLine();
        file = new File(filename);
        if (!file.exists())
            System.out.println("The specifed file does not exist - please try again!");

    }while( !file.exists());
    return file;

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you set a special delimiter on the character scanner?  Also, the comments in your character count code make it clear you are counting words, not characters.  What makes you think that your method *should* be counting characters (apart from its name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the characters in the file, excluding any *whitespace*, you can read your file line by line and accumulate the character count, or read the whole file in a `String` and do the character count, e.g.

```
String content = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(content.charAt(i))) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

---

**EDIT**
Other solutions if you don't care about the content of the file, then there is no need to load it into a `String`, you can just read character by character.

Example counting the non-whitespace characters in [Arthur Rimbaud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Rimbaud) poetry.

#### Using a `Scanner`

```
    URL rimbaud = new URL("http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/29302/pg29302.txt");
    int count = 0;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rimbaud.openStream()))) {
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

#### Using a plain `StreamReader`

```
    count = 0;
    try (Scanner sin = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(rimbaud.openStream())))) {
        sin.useDelimiter("");
        char c;
        while (sin.hasNext()) {
            c = sin.next().charAt(0);
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```